# How to prove that $(1-y) \;\text{csch}\;[x (1-y)]>\text{csch}(x)$ for $0<y<2$?

Tags: inequality, hyperbolic-functions

I want to prove that this inequality
$$(1-y) \;\text{csch}\;[x (1-y)]>\text{csch}(x)$$
holds for $x>0$ and $0<y<2$?

Any hints and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This is equivalent to $\sinh(x)/x$ increasing for $x > 0$. That $1-y$ is a clever disguise. See my answer.

Comment: It suffices to prove that $x(1-y) \operatorname{csch} x(1-y) > x \operatorname{csch} x$. Let $f(u) = u \operatorname{csch} u$. We need to prove that $f(u)$ is strictly decreasing on $[0, \infty)$. Just take derivatives.

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks for your comment, this might work.

Answer (score 2):

Note:
In response to comments,
I assume that
$x > 0$ and
$y < 1$.
I will show later
(it is late here)
that this will take care
of the other cases.

Want
$(1-y)/\sinh(x (1-y))
\gt 1/\sinh(x)
$
for
$0 < y < 2$
or
$(1-y)\sinh(x)
\gt \sinh(x(1-y))
$.

Letting $z = 1-y$,
this is
$z\sinh(x)
\gt \sinh(zx)
$
for $-1 < z < 1$.

Dividing by $zx$,
this is
$\dfrac{\sinh(x)}{x}
\gt \dfrac{\sinh(zx)}{zx}
$.

Since $\sinh(x)/x$
is even,
we only need to look at
$x > 0, z > 0$.

Since $f(x)=\sinh(x)/x$ is increasing
(see below)
and $f(0) = 1$,
and $0 < z < 1$,
$zx < x$
so
$\dfrac{\sinh(zx)}{zx}
\lt \dfrac{\sinh(x)}{x}
$.

To show
$f(x)=\sinh(x)/x$ is increasing
for $x > 0$:

$\sinh(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
$
so
$\dfrac{\sinh(x)}{x}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}
=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}
$
so that
$\left(\dfrac{\sinh(x)}{x}\right)'
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2nx^{2n-1}}{(2n+1)!}
\gt 0$
for $x > 0$.

(Added later)

So we want
$z/\sinh(xz)
\gt 1/\sinh(x)
$
where
$|z| < 1$.

I show above this is true for
$0 < z < 1$
and
$x > 0$.
I will now consider
the other cases.
The basic identity used is
$\sinh(-x) = -\sinh(x)
$.

If $-1 < z < 0$
and $x > 0$
then
$\dfrac{z}{\sinh(xz)}
=\dfrac{-z}{-\sinh(xz)}
=\dfrac{-z}{\sinh(x(-z))}
$
so this is the same
as above.

If $-1 < z < 0$
and $x < 0$
then
$\dfrac{z}{\sinh(xz)}
=-\dfrac{-z}{\sinh((-x)(-z))}
$
and
$\dfrac1{\sinh(x)}
=-\dfrac1{\sinh(-x)}$
so
$z/\sinh(xz)
\gt 1/\sinh(x)
$
is the same as
$-\dfrac{-z}{\sinh((-x)(-z))}
\gt -\dfrac1{\sinh(-x)}
$
or
$\dfrac{-z}{\sinh((-x)(-z))}
\lt \dfrac1{\sinh(-x)}
$
and in this case
the inequality is reversed
since the signs are reversed.

If $z > 0$
and $x < 0$
then
$\dfrac{z}{\sinh(xz)}
=-\dfrac{z}{\sinh((-x)z)}
$
and
$\dfrac1{\sinh(x)}
=-\dfrac1{\sinh(-x)}$
so
$z/\sinh(xz)
\gt 1/\sinh(x)
$
is the same as
$-\dfrac{z}{\sinh((-x)z)}
\gt -\dfrac1{\sinh(-x)}
$
or
$\dfrac{z}{\sinh((-x)z)}
\lt \dfrac1{\sinh(-x)}
$
and in this case
the inequality is reversed
since the signs are reversed.

Therefore
the inequality is reversed
when $x < 0$.

Comment: The problem is so simple .... after reading the nice solution ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @martycohen   Please check: $z\sinh(x) \gt \sinh(zx)$, dividing by $zx$, but $zx$ can be negative.

Comment: Since $\sinh(x)/x$ is even, we only need to look at $x>0, z>0$.

Comment: @martycohen But you just say this later. You should say this before, otherwise, you can not get: $z\sinh(x) \gt \sinh(zx)$ for $-1 < z < 1$, Dividing by $zx$, that
is $\dfrac{\sinh(x)}{x} \gt \dfrac{\sinh(zx)}{zx}$.

Comment: Also check your first line: $(1-y)/\sinh(x (1-y))
\gt 1/\sinh(x)$ for $0 < y < 2$, or $(1-y)\sinh(x)
\gt \sinh(x(1-y))$. At this moment, you do not assume $0 < y < 1$,
you can not get the latter.

Answer (score 1):

If $y \ne 1,$ then $y = 1 \pm t,$ where $t > 0,$ and the inequality to be proved is equivalent to
$$
\frac{\sinh(tx)}{tx} < \frac{\sinh x}x \quad (x > 0, \ 0 < t < 1).
$$
An equivalent statement is that the function
$$
g(x) = \frac{\sinh x}x \quad (x \ne 0)
$$
is strictly increasing for $x > 0.$

We have
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac12\left(\frac{e^x - 1}x + \frac{1 - e^{-x}}x\right) = 1,
$$
so, if $g(x)$ is strictly increasing for $x > 0,$ it follows that:
$$
g(x) > 1 \quad (x > 0),
$$
and therefore:
$$
\lim_{y \to 1}((1 - y)\operatorname{csch}(x(1 - y))) =
\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t}{\sinh(tx)} =
\lim_{t \to 0}\frac1{xg(tx)} =
\frac1x > \operatorname{csch} x \quad (x > 0),
$$
which gives a reasonable interpretation to the stated inequality in the strictly meaningless case $y = 1.$

As for the main case:
$$
g'(x) = \frac{x\cosh x - \sinh x}{x^2} = \frac{(\cosh x)(x - \tanh x)}{x^2} > 0 \quad (x > 0).
$$
This follows from the first of the two inequalities **(2)** that were proved in my answer to the OP's more recent question [Any idea to prove that $\coth (x)-(1-y) \coth [x (1-y)]<\frac{4 x}{1-x^4}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808663/any-idea-to-prove-that-coth-x-1-y-coth-x-1-y-frac4-x1-x4)

Repeating - and slightly extending - that proof here, to make this answer self-contained:

The graph of the convex function $u \mapsto 1/u$ lies above the tangent at $(1, 1),$ therefore
$$
2x < \int_{1 - x}^{1 + x}\frac{du}u = \log\frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \quad (0 < x < 1),
$$
therefore
$$
(1 - x)e^{2x} < 1 + x \quad (x > 0),
$$
because this inequality holds trivially if $x \geqslant 1.$

Therefore, for all $x > 0,$ $e^{2x} - 1 < x(e^{2x} + 1).$ Equivalently,
$$
\tanh x < x \quad (x > 0),
$$
which gives $g'(x) > 0,$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for comments.*

At least, around integer values of $y$, series expansions shows the inequality since we have
$$\text{lhs - rhs} = (x \coth (x)-1)\, \text{csch}(x)\,y+O\left(y^2\right)$$
$$\text{lhs - rhs} =\frac{1}{x}-\text{csch}(x)+O\left((y-1)^2\right)$$
$$\text{lhs - rhs} = (x \coth (x)-1)\, \text{csch}(x)\,(2-y)+O\left((y-2)^2\right)$$

Comment: Equivalent to $\sinh(x)/x$ increasing for $x > 0$. See my answer.